# Is it possible to merge two GIT trees according to date?

Tags: git, merge

Suppose we have two people in a group. We maintain two GIT trees A and B, I work on A and the other guy works on B.

I created file a on March 1st, file c on March 3rd in A.

> a - March 1st
>    c - March 3rd

And the other guy created file b on March 2nd in B.

> b - March 2nd

Is it possible to merge two trees so I have a new tree which looks like:

> a - March 1st
>    b - March 2nd
>    c - March 3rd

and when I checkout files for March 2nd, I will get file a and b?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a script to check-in every commit one by one. It is stupid but I guess that is an easy way and probably the only way I know to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible with an interactive rebase, but I'd question the use case: It seems that there was no repository on March 2nd which contained a and b, so what are the semantics of saying “check out files for March 2nd”?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The use case is, when people want to use an external library, they may want to integrate code of it. Because when they check out their code, they can check out external library code that provides same APIs. Yes, APIs should not change too often if well designed. But let's say this is the problem we want to solve. If it's like what you said, there is no repo on March 2nd, I would like to have a way to get a and b for March 2nd, either use merge or any other way.

Comment: @echo: Exactly in that situation, I would stay the hell away from what you describe. You would get an untested combination of commits that never before has been in any developer's system this way and is likely to be inconsistent. Do a standard git merge and check out versions which your developers tested and committed; most easily using these strange hex number strings. Move your mind away from a linear model of version history, use a graphical tool like GitX to look at the history of your repository, and you'll be glad git doesn't just look at individual files, but the whole repository.